# Why navbar doubled after using "repeat" in CSS?

Tags: css, navbar, repeat

I wanted to create a navbar on my website, with background using the repeat of an orange block of image. Here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tyXr.png). However, the final result shows a doubled navbar as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwMP.png). It remains doubled even after changing the "repeat" attribute in css. How do I make it only 1 layer instead of being doubled?

Here is my css code:

```
#cssmenu{
      border-style: initial;
    border-color: initial;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
     padding:0px;
        border-image-source:initial;
        border-image-slice:initial;
        border-image-width:initial;
        border-image-outset:initial;
        border-image-repeat:initial;

        list-style-type:none;
        list-style-position:initial;
        list-style-image: initial;


        line-height:1;
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;


        background-image: url('../../SiteAssets/o.png');
        background-repeat:repeat;
        background-repeat-x:repeat;
        background-repeat-y:repeat;
        z-index:2;


    }

    #cssmenu:after{

    content:".";
    z-index:2;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
    line-height:0;
    height:0;

}
```

and my html code:

```
<div id="cssmenu" style="left:0px; top:0px" >
        <ul>
           <li>
              <!--main-->
             <ul><!--dropdownlist--></ul>
           </li>
           <li>
               <!--main-->
             <ul><!--dropdownlist--></ul>
           </li>
           <li>
                <!--main-->
             <ul><!--dropdownlist--></ul>
           </li>
           <li>
                <!--main-->
             <ul><!--dropdownlist--></ul>
           </li>
           <li>
                <!--main-->
             <ul><!--dropdownlist--></ul>
           </li>

        </ul>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right behavior. You are repeating the background image on the y axis, and because of the gradient you have in there you see it two time. The image is to small for the height of the navbar. So either set `background-size: auto 100%`, or BETTER: use background gradient.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help it works! The navbar looks too "tall" vertically. Is there any way to make it shorter? @Marc Wissler

Comment: I assume you want the navigation items spread out horizontally. So add display inline-block to the ul I think

Answer (score 0):

say your code background-image is repeated so image is showing as a doubled navbar. Add this code in css background-size: 100% 100%; in #cssmenu